# How can i unserialize my form data in controller ? Ruby on Rails version 4

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have submitted form data using ajax method and my form data serialized from html page. I want to unserialize the content as we do in parsestr in php.Please help me

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse, but normally params object is already parsed.

Comment: can you submit what you are getting at the php server?

Comment: I got the below content after using this code 
Code : @inputDets = CGI::parse(params[:data])
Result : 
{"id"=>"", "data"=>"name=testname&type=create&aliasname=test&aliases%5B1%5D=test&aliases%5B2%5D=test1", "action"=>"add", "controller"=>"app/test"}